# do some public Socrata data sets require login for programmatic access?

Tags: socrata

I'm trying to get started using public Socrata data.

I understand using the URL to request a data set, and see it is very easy in a browser.

But when I put the same url in a simple script that runs a web request, I get errors.

In one tool, I get

```html
{   "error" : true,   "message" : "You must be logged in to access this resource" }
```

In another type of simple coding, I get

```html
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

- Is that a correct behavior, that sites participating in SODA may only allow anonymous access in a browser?

( Or do I have a mistake in my script making the request? )

---

(EDIT --- I don't like hinting and biasing answers, but I am narrowing in on SSL stuff...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no. Data published that you can access on a web browser (without logging in) is also available over API without login.

However, if you create a private view (like filtering a public data set), then you will need to pass your login credentials over the API.

So, one way to test it is if you can view the data through a web browser without logging in.

Comment: I'm seeing possibly some problem with the https security protocols...    might that also be correct?

Comment: Would need more specifics on what you're seeing. Haven't seen this error before so suspect not. If you can provide more specifics on how you're request is being formulated or the URL, then it can be validated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   In fact, I have rather well isolated it to how my scripting implements ssl.  Which does mean your answer is correct :)  I'll raise and/or answer - the other issues in other questions.

Comment: One thing you might add to your answer, if it's correct...... maybe Write access always requires login, and POST requests may be assumed as Write and cause the first error --- so be sure to use GET for reads (?)